# Socket.io (with NodeJS) - Client not getting disconnection event

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, client-side

I have this code to detect disconnection on client side.

The connection event is correctly caught but when the connection drops (I've  forced it trough Chrome device mode) the disconnect event isn't caught and nothing is written on the console.

```
var socket = io();
    socket.on("connect", function(){
        console.log("Client connected.");
        this.on("disconnect", function(){
            console.error("Client disconnected");
        });
    });
```

(I also tried with separate functions and other events like connect_error but it's the same

```
socket.on("connect", ...)
socket.on("connect_error", ...)
socket.on("disconnect", ...)
```

Could you please tell me what's wrong with that event?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {...});
```

instead of

```
this.on("disconnect", function() {...});
```

Another thing is that based on [socket.io documentation](http://socket.io/docs/) for connection the correct syntax is:

```
socket.on('connection', function(){...});
```

Comment: I think you're confusing server side and client-side code.. on("connection") is server-side. Also 'this' refers to the socket itself inside that function

Answer (score 0):

Well, Simo's answer is proper and what you are doing is also correct but with one correction.

When you listen to connection, your recieve a socket object along with it and you use it to handle disconnection . I guess using the this context is the problem.

```
socket.on("connect", function(socket){
    socket.on("disconnected",function(){})
}
```

Try this out. It works

Comment: You're wrong, no parameter is passed to the function, and the docs report: "connect. Fired upon connecting.", no parameter given..